# EaselJS - scale Container without scaling certain children of container

Tags: javascript, maps, scale, createjs, easeljs

I am creating a project in CreateJS (specifically, EaselJS) where I have a draggable map. There are several wrinkles to this that I'm trying to figure out my way around.

Basically, when the user drags the map to certain points, the map is supposed to automatically zoom in or out (i.e. the scaleX and scaleY of the map container change), in order to focus on areas of interest.

This would be fairly simple and I in fact already have a prototype that does this— there's just one problem.
The map has a layer of map markers (pins on the map) floating above it. When the map zooms in, these map markers need to stay stuck to their underlying places on the map.

Making markers children of the map's Container is the logical step, but there's a further problem with that: The markers are in the correct places, but when the map zooms in, the markers get larger. When it zooms out, the markers get smaller.

Is there an efficient way I can prevent these markers' containers from being scaled themselves, only moved in step with the parent Container's scaling?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting everything in the same Container, use multiple Containers, and use `localToGlobal` to position labels. It will be more work, but its really the only way.

You could counter-scale the labels, but Container's main purpose is to translate and transform a group of display objects together.

Comment: So far so good, but is that computationally efficient? The map will have several HUNDRED markers, several dozen of which may be visible at any one time. Coordinates for all will need to be checked/updated to show them each tick of the user's drag and... I worry it'll lag the browser.

Comment: It will definitely be less performant because the transformation has to be calculated separately, but that overhead will be minimal. It would be about the same as counter-scaling the sub-elements though.